# Overlay with spinner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay that overlays a page with a spinner in the middle.  What's the simplest way to accomplish this?  I only need to worry about IE 8 and above.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

use a css3 class "spinner". It's more beautiful and you don't need .gif

[image]

```css
    .spinner {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       top: 50%;
       height:60px;
       width:60px;
       margin:0px auto;
       -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
       -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
       -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
       animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
       border-left:6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
       border-right:6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
       border-bottom:6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
       border-top:6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.8);
       border-radius:100%;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
       from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
    }
    @-moz-keyframes rotation {
       from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {-moz-transform: rotate(359deg);}
    }
    @-o-keyframes rotation {
       from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {-o-transform: rotate(359deg);}
    }
    @keyframes rotation {
       from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
       to {transform: rotate(359deg);}
    }
```

Exemple of what is looks like : http://jsbin.com/roqakuxebo/1/edit

You can find a lot of css spinners like this here : http://cssload.net/en/spinners/

Comment: NOTE: CSS Transforms not supported in IE8, and for IE9 you need the -ms- prefix

Comment: This is really nice, but how can you give the spinner a background color that will overlay for example a login control?

Answer (score 39):

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black url(spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

it's better to use rgba color instead of opacity to prevent applying alpha to spinner image.

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5) url(spinner.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: This works perfect, but I have a fixed `div` on the page which it doesn't overlay.... do I need to work with z-indexes to get that to work?

Comment: @Webnet then obvously you've got it wrong in your code. you could try `position: absolute`

Comment: Probably want to add `top: 0; bottom: 0;` to make it cover the whole page

Answer (score 7):

Here is simple overlay div without using any gif, This can be applied over another div.

```
<style>
.loader {
  position: relative;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: .5;
}
.container{
    position:relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Overlay over this div</h3>
  <div id="overlay">
      <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Over any div that has `position: relative`, otherwise it will cover the whole page.

Comment: @Savage that is a trick that should be reinforced

Answer (score 2):

And for a spinner like iOs I use this:

[image]

html:

```
  <div class='spinner'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
.spinner {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.spinner div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.4629em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.074em;
  height: 0.2777em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
      -ms-transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
          transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
          animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
}
.spinner div:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.083s;
          animation-delay: 0.083s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.166s;
          animation-delay: 0.166s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.249s;
          animation-delay: 0.249s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.332s;
          animation-delay: 0.332s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.415s;
          animation-delay: 0.415s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
          transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.498s;
          animation-delay: 0.498s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.581s;
          animation-delay: 0.581s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
          transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.664s;
          animation-delay: 0.664s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
          transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.747s;
          animation-delay: 0.747s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
          transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.83s;
          animation-delay: 0.83s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
          transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.spinner div:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.913s;
          animation-delay: 0.913s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
          transform: rotate(330deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

get from this website : https://365webresources.com/10-best-pure-css-loading-spinners-front-end-developers/

Answer (score 1):

As an update, for Angular 7, a very good example, loading plus http interceptor, here: https://nezhar.com/blog/create-a-loading-screen-for-angular-apps/.

For version 6, you need a small adjustment when you use Subject. You need to add the generic type.

```
loadingStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

I'm using angular material, so instead of a loading text, you can use mat-spinner.

```
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

Update: the code from the previous page will not complete work (regarding the interceptor part), but here you have the complete solution: https://github.com/nezhar/snypy-frontend

And as Miranda recommended into comments, here is also the solution:

The loading screen component:

loading-screen.component.ts

```
    import { Component, ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { LoadingScreenService } from '../services/loading-screen.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading-screen',
  templateUrl: './loading-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading-screen.component.css']
})
export class LoadingScreenComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  loading: boolean = false;
  loadingSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private loadingScreenService: LoadingScreenService,
    private _elmRef: ElementRef,
    private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._elmRef.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    this.loadingSubscription = this.loadingScreenService.loadingStatus.pipe().subscribe(
      (status: boolean) => {
        this._elmRef.nativeElement.style.display = status ? 'block' : 'none';
        this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("inside destroy loading component");
    this.loadingSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

loading-screen.component.html

```
<div id="overlay">
  <mat-spinner class="content"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

loading-screen.component.css

```
  #overlay {
      position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
      display: block; /* Hidden by default */
      width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
      height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(60, 138, 255, 0.1); /* Black background with opacity */
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 2; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
      cursor: progress; /* Add a pointer on hover */
  }

  .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: white;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Don't forget to add the component to your root component. In my case, AppComponent

app.component.html

```
<app-loading-screen></app-loading-screen>
```

The service that will manage the component: loading-screen.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingScreenService {

  constructor() { }

  private _loading: boolean = false;
  loadingStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  get loading(): boolean {
    console.log("get loading: " + this._loading);
    return this._loading;
  }

  set loading(value) {
    console.log("get loading: " + value);
    this._loading = value;
    this.loadingStatus.next(value);
  }

  startLoading() {
    console.log("startLoading");
    this.loading = true;
  }

  stopLoading() {
    console.log("stopLoading");
    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

Here is the http interceptor, which will show/hide the component, using the previous service.

loading-screen-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoadingScreenService } from '../services/loading-screen.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingScreenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    activeRequests: number = 0;

    constructor(
        private loadingScreenService: LoadingScreenService
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log("inside interceptor");

        if (this.activeRequests === 0) {
            this.loadingScreenService.startLoading();
        }

        this.activeRequests++;

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                this.activeRequests--;
                if (this.activeRequests === 0) {
                    this.loadingScreenService.stopLoading();
                }
            })
        )
    };
}
```

And in your app.module.ts, don't forget to config the interceptor

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoadingScreenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Comment: this is very over-engineered don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Pure CSS endless spinner. Position absolute, to place the buttons on top of each other.

```css
button {
            position: absolute;
            width: 150px;
            font-size: 120%;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #B52519;
            color: #EAEAEA;
            border: none;
            margin: 50px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: flex;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #orderButton:hover {
            color: #c8c8c8;
        }

        #orderLoading {
            animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 100%;
            border: 2px solid;
            border-style: outset;
            color: #fff;
        }

        @keyframes rotation {
            from {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
```

```html
<button><div id="orderLoading"></div></button>
<button id="orderButton" onclick="this.style.visibility= 'hidden';">Order!</button>
```